Thunderbird keeps asking for login passwords after ugrading to Ubuntu 24.04 (not totally stable...)
I just upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04. I know it is not totally stable nor LTS...
ThunderBird is now with snap.
I use the --profile manager to get to my old profile.
Unfortunately it does not recognize my login passwords. It keeps on asking for them. And I cannot even access my accounts (Gmail, Orange and others).
I tried different solutions proposed here : delete/rename various files in the default folder (pkcs11.txt or [cert8.db and cert9.db, key4.db and prefs.js] ) without any success.
What can I do?
Is the fact that ThunderBird is with snap a possible reason?
My profile folder is on an external drive  (formatted ext3/ext4). Another possible reason?
Upgrade on a version of Ubuntu still in progress...?
Is there anything preventing on Google side (I use OAuth)? I even tried to go back to my simple passwords... no success...
SOLUTION:
I installed the apt version as Rinzwind proposed and I found my ThunderBird back !
The snap version needs "a link from inside the snap to outside the snap and those are blocked by default."  One just needs to know!
I followed this how-to :
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/03/install-thunderbird-deb-ubuntu-2404/
Thank you all!

"Is the fact that ThunderBird is with snap a possible reason? " was it a snap before the upgrade? FF was acting up on my machine and  that was due to snap. "My profile folder is on an external drive (formatted ext3/ext4)." makes it very likely. You need a link from inside the snap to outside the  snap and those are blocked by default. I installed the apt version from the mozilla ppa.... there is also pne for TB ;)

when I re-installed TB on my scratch PC running 23.10 I found exactly the same issueseven though they were fine in the 22.04 instance. How I fixed this was to go in to the TB menu ≡ Tools > Export and exported the accounts, Messages addresses and settings to an export ZIP file and then in the new installation navigate to the same menu option but then select import and imported the file I had created. That seemed to fix all the issues I had been experiencing.

Just to add - I've since done the same thing on a new install of Betterbird Flatpak instance (a TB derivative) on Debian 12 which worked equally well and no issues. I'd venture to suggest you create this file in the upgraded version then delete the TB instance and re-install importing the data from the ZIP file as described. If that works, I'll post it as an answer.

Thank you Rinzwind
! It did the trick! It was not a snap before the upgrade and I understand now why it could not work... It needs "a link from inside the snap to outside the snap and those are blocked by default." I installed the apt version and I found my ThunderBird back ! Thank you so much !
