Thunderbird 115 wrong profile location
I wonder if anyone made the same or similar experience.
Thunderbird 115 included in 24.04 LTS installation.
My profiles are located on the SD card working well on other two laptops running ubuntu 22.04. Swap SD cards with profiles between two laptops is my way of working with Thunderbird since 13.04.
After installation 24.04 (and Thunderbird 115.10.1 included). Following the instruction for adding old profile to the new Thunderbird. Help->Thunderbird information->about:profiles. Creating new profile.

Using the function CHOOSE FOLDER indicated the path to the profile /media/VB/AB49-E208/Thunderbird profile
The path to the folder shown by Thunderbird is different (and strange): /run/user/1000/doc/58235/Thunderbird

When looking into the directory tree the folder is empty (obviously).
Thunderbird therefore cannot reach the profile located on SD card and doesn't work.
How could I overwrite the strange path by the right one ?

You are probably running the snap version of Thunderbird which has all the issues associated with snaps including file/directory access. Consider installing the .deb version of Thunderbird.

Yes, I do. Thanks. I tried a .deb file found mozilla PPA but during installation in 24.04 there were three errors "missing library" so I abandoned. At the same time I read that starting 24.04 they decided to provide snap only version. Thanks for your comment, very helpful.

The solution found with help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512450/thunderbird-keeps-asking-for-login-passwords-after-ugrading-to-ubuntu-24-04-not
